# Constant variable in global scope or in repeated function

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js

I'm building a virtual space with Three.js, integrating 3D assets and spatial sound, so it can be quite performance-challenging. I have a function that is called at each frame (each 1/60 second), and I was wondering where to put the constant variables, for it to spend as little resources as it could.

I'm thinking I should better put it in the global scope, so it won't be assigned again at each frame. But I've learned I should avoid "polluting" the global scope as much as I can, and this variable is required only in that given function.

So, should I put it in the global scope, therefore polluting it a little ? Are re-assigning it each time and reading it from the global scope the same, performance-wise ?

Here is the function to provide some insight, the constant variable is `EASING_FACTOR` :

```js
function easeTransition(current, old) {
  const EASING_FACTOR = 100;
  let result = {};
  for (const arg in current) {
    const diff = current[arg] - old[arg];
    result[arg] = old[arg] + diff / EASING_FACTOR;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You calmly use `const EASING_FACTOR=100`at te top ate the function or the whole code, if you really do not want to modify it. (A little comment: the best way, if there is a real code part, you can just type 100 every time - it is the least slow method, if you do not use different operations to get the number).

Comment: Why not omit it completely: `result[arg] = old[arg] + diff / 100` if it's only used once.

Comment: @user17517503 @Onki Hara Thank you both for your answer. Well I wanted to use a constant for better code readability, but it's indeed not necessary. I'll be better typing `100` and add a comment to explain the purpose. It's obviously the fastest way. Thanks!

Comment: This would be called a "magic number" and is generally considered poor form. If 100 is an easing factor, call it easing factor, dont leave arbitrary numbers and strings around with no meaning.

Comment: But yeah if you absolutely must do that, multiply by 0.01 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const EASING_FACTOR = 100;
const EASING_FACTOR_INVERSE = 1/EASING_FACTOR

function easeTransition(current, old) {
  let result = {};
  for (const arg in current) {
    const diff = current[arg] - old[arg];
    result[arg] = old[arg] + diff * EASING_FACTOR_INVERSE;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Divisions are slower than multiplications, so it would make sense to compute the inverse once and then do thousands of multiplications instead of divisions.

Other patterns should help you avoid polluting the global scope. I'm actually not sure about the terminology here (what kind of modules etc) but if this code is in one file, you would only export the `easeTransition` function, thus your constants wouldn't actually be global.

If you want to try this "manually" you would use an IIFE:

```
const easeTransition = (function(){
  const EASING_FACTOR = 100;
  return function _easeTransition(current, old) {
    let result = {};
    for (const arg in current) {
      const diff = current[arg] - old[arg];
      result[arg] = old[arg] + diff / EASING_FACTOR;
    }
    return result;
  }
})() //<- this invokes it "immediately"
```

`const EASING_FACTOR` is now in a "closure" and the only thing you expose is the inner function.

Comment: Ohh... This is great, I had no idea about multiplications being faster than divisions. I did not think about using an IIFE that way either, thanks a lot for your advice! (And from this day, I'm banishing "magic numbers").

Comment: There is some magic that a compiler will do and possibly diminish these results, but check this out: https://jsbench.me/2al2oytoko/1

Comment: Oh this is A LOT faster! I never thought about using this kind of tool... But next step is testing (with Jest), so it's pretty much in the topic. There is a lot of stuff I want to compare now with this, thanks again!